# window.location not working by using get element by id

Tags: javascript, html

Hello i'm here with a new question in following code ,in below code `window.location` is not working, though `window.alert` is working perfect showing my desired url and value of `emailid` for which im writing this code. A Little help needed,I im new in this field.Your little help would make me learn better.Thanks in advance.

```
<html> 
<form> 
<input id="c" type="hidden" value="http://mydomain.com"/>
<input id="d" type="hidden" value="/somefile.php?emailid=/> 
<h5>Your Email adress</h5>
<br>
<input id="e" type="text"><br>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="display_alert();" /> 
</form>
<script lang="javascript"> 
function display_alert() 
{ var dn = document.getElementById('d'); var cn = document.getElementById('c'); 
  var fn = document.getElementById('a');
  var ln = document.getElementById('e'); }
 location = "cn.value + dn.value + ln.value";
 </script> 
 </html>
```

Answer (score 5):

`location` isn't a function. **Assign** a value to it with `=`, don't call it with `()`.

---

Or remove the unnecessary dependancy on JS entirely:

```
<form action="http://mydomain.com/somefile.php">
<label>Your Email address
<input name="emailid"></label>
<input type="submit" value="submit"> 
</form>
```

---

Update in response to the question being edited:

If you want values stored in variables to be concatenated, then you need to use the actual variables and not put the code to concatenate them inside a string literal.

Comment: But how to take value of ` emailid` from html page itself and pass it through url.?

Comment: @VikrantKelkar — By using an input with a name: `<input name="emailid">`

Comment: Also assigning `=` doesn't opens the desired url but only remains blank.

Comment: Also im avoiding `$_POST['emailid']` method, ,i want to send values through url only.

Comment: The form doesn't have `method=POST` so it *will* be sent through the URL.

Comment: I edited code, but this is not working.? This is the exact code i have.

Comment: @VikrantKelkar — I've already updated the answer to compensate for that edit. You should still use a regular form without any JS for this though.

Comment: Will $_GET['emailid'] print the value of emailid in my next page?

Comment: Only if you put a `print` or `echo` before it.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as below, as location is property

```
window.location = cn.value + dn.value + ln.value;
```

Comment: Your ans is not working, nothing happens when preesed go button